# Check if elements from the list are visible in the WebElement text

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm having really simple & stupid case which I cannot handle correctly:

General idea:

- Make list of strings which contain address elements (like: name, surname, street etc.)
- Get WebElement with all of those data on DOM
- Loop over the list and compare if specific list element is enclosed inside taken WebElement

Create list of strings:

```
List<String> accountBillingAddressData = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Mevrouw","Jan Kowalski", "testStreet","15","1234567","1234WW","Amsterdam","Nederland"));
```

Get WebElement text:

```
String billingAddress = StringUtils.normalizeSpace(baseMethods.findElement("CheckoutPage.Billing.Section").getText());
```

"findElements" name is wrapped in the framework.

DOM element looks like:

```html
<div class="address" bis_skin_checked="1">
  <p>
    Mevrouw Jan Kowalski<br>
    testStreet 15<br>
    1234567<br>
    1234WW Amsterdam
    <br> Nederland
  </p>
</div>
```

Locator is: `.address > p`

---

Code:

```
List<String> accountBillingAddressData = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Mevrouw","Jan Kowalski", "testStreet","15","1234567","1234WW","Amsterdam","Nederland"));
String billingAddress = StringUtils.normalizeSpace(baseMethods.findElement("CheckoutPage.Billing.Address").getText());
for (String addressElement : accountBillingAddressData){
    if(!billingAddress.contains(addressElement));
    {
        Assert.fail("Billing address does not contain specific data");
    }
}
```

Data from list and WebElement looks correct as well. However if loops keeps going inside and fails....

[image: Method in code]

Comment: My be it is case sensitive issue, Can you please print both web element  text and array element string before `if` clause and check any case mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
There was mistake inside the if:

```
if(!billingAddress.contains(addressElement));
    {
        Assert.fail("Billing address does not contain specific data");
    }
```

it should be:

```
if(!billingAddress.contains(addressElement)){
        Assert.fail("Billing address does not contain specific data");
    }
```